# How to get scrollY position of a scrollable popup

Tags: javascript, html

While scrolling a scrollable div on a pop-up, I need the y coordinates, using window.scrollY return y coordinates of background body, not of popup. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Add some code you have tried so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a scroll event to the element which is scrollable.

```
const div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
div.addEventListener("scroll", (e)=> {
  console.log("scrollTop: " + e.scrollTop);
});
```